# IE6 Centered Content Bug

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, center

I have some centered content within a div. It shows up fine in Firefox/Chrome. In IE6 the content expands beyond the div to the entire browser window. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you post the HTML and the relevant style information, as well as possibly a screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: Include a snippet of HTML and the relevant styles.

Answer (score 1):

### IE6 Workaround

The thing to do is to have text-align: center on a parent div e.g. body, so that your content div is centered in IE6.

Then use margin: auto on the content block to make sure the div is centered in better browsers.

### CSS

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the doctype definition at the top of your page. Otherwise, IE6 will open the page in quirks mode which can screw all kinds of stuff up...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

The <center> tag is deprecated. You should do something like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;">
</div>
```

That way you will have centered content.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined the doctype and I am centering the content with CSS.

Comment: Please provide you updates as edits to your question, don't answer your own question unless its truly and answer.  This is not a thread style forum.